# MySQL ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE see what was updated

Tags: php, mysql, insert-update

I have a query that checks whether to increment a user's game play streak.

```
INSERT INTO PlayStreak (id, curr_streak, last_play_date) 
VALUES (?, 1, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
 curr_streak = CASE 
                 WHEN last_play_date = ? THEN curr_streak + 1 
                 WHEN last_play_date < ? THEN 1 
               END
 last_play_date = ?
```

It basically checks if the `last_play_date` was yesterday (in which case increment the streak) or *before* yesterday, in which reset the streak to one because the user skipped a day.

Is there a way to see when the streak was reset to 1 without doing a separate `SELECT` statement? When this is the case, I want to do some PHP logging for my records. MySQL's `affected_rows` will only tell me *if* the row was updated, not *how* it was updated. Any thoughts?

Comment: You will probably have to compare the before and after results to get what you want. Then log them to your desired medium. There is another function in the MySQLi package which will net you some info, based on that info you could log or choose not to. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php This will tell you how many rows where matched and changed on an UPDATE query. If the amount of rows changed > 0 you would have to compare both data sets and make a decision if you want to log something. Hope this helps in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Nope, you need to do an extra select to determine such sub-result.

Comment: Yeah I figured I'd have to have a separate select statement, but the mysqli->info statement is still helpful. Thanks all